# How to use .a file for iOS with Flutter FFI?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ffi, dart-ffi

I have a rust project. Compiling it to .so for android, I'm able to run it with Android. I have also generated .a file for iOS and used instructions for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67494521/10906949) but it's throwing following error: `Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'LibStackmatePlugin' /Users/mohitsingh/Desktop/myapp/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:17:3`.

GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m is as follows:

```
//
//  Generated file. Do not edit.
//

// clang-format off

#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<libstackmate/LibStackmatePlugin.h>)
#import <libstackmate/LibStackmatePlugin.h>
#else
@import libstackmate;
#endif

@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
  [LibStackmatePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"LibStackmatePlugin"]];
}

@end
```

Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Please update the question showing the contents of `/Users/mohitsingh/Desktop/myapp/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`

Comment: @RichardHeap, updated the question with ```/Users/mohitsingh/Desktop/myapp/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m```. The .a file is named ```libstackmate.a```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my `pubspec.yaml` file. It defined plugin as

```yaml
      android:
        package: com.example.libstackmate
        pluginClass: LibstackmatePlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: LibstackmatePlugin
```

but in ios/app, plugin was defined as LibStackmatePlugin. Due to this name mismatch, I was getting this error. The error was resolved by updating ios pluginClass name in `pubspec.yaml`.